# Text directly in body

Tags: html

Is it allowed for text to be placed directly in the HTML `body` element, by the HTML standards, like in the following piece of HTML:

```
<body>
    Some text
</body>
```

Or is it only allowed to place the text in another HTML element, like in the following piece of HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>Some text</p>
</body>
```

The reason I am asking this is because I know the following is invalid HTML 5:

```
<body>
    <span>Some text</span>
</body>
```

This is invalid because inline elements (like `span`) should always be placed inside block level elements (like `p`). Therefore, it seems unlikely to me that it would be allowed to place text outside of any elements, directly in the `body`.

Also, does it matter which version of the HTML standard we are talking about?

Comment: Have a good read and find out: http://www.w3.org/

Comment: @MelanciaUK I searched for it there, but I couldn't find an answer. Besides, I think this is an interesting question to have on stackoverflow.

Comment: Probably depends on the browser. Some are more forgiving of this kind of thing than others.

Comment: I didn't question the importance of your question. I just pointed out a source for reference. Put the text straight into the page body and check with the validation tool provided.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Oh I am sorry, I misunderstood you then. It is indeed a good source for reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text directly inside the `body` element is allowed e.g. in HTML 4.01 Transitional and in HTML5, but not in HTML 4.01 Strict. So it really depends on HTML version. And it is really just a formality; the different definitions reflect just different views of good coding style.

The same applies to inline elements like `span`. They, too, *are* allowed in HTML5 as children of `body`.

Answer (score 3):

On the `w3.org` [validator page](http://validator.w3.org/docs/errors.html), it explains some errors, of which error 63 answers your question:

> 63: character data is not allowed here
>
> You have used character data somewhere it is not permitted to appear.
>   Mistakes that can cause this error include:
>
> - putting text directly in the body of the document without wrapping it in a container element (such as a `<p>aragraph</p>`)

This was found with a google search for "w3 text allowed in body"

Comment: This applies to some versions only.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of using that search string and using the validator. I think the error you quoted only appears when validating an HTML 4.01 Strict document, because when using other HTML versions for validating, the error doesn't appear. That suggests that putting text directly directly in the body is allowed in all HTML standards, except in HTML 4.01 Strict.

Answer (score 0):

Placing text directly into the body tag such as this:

```
<body>
    Insert text directly into the body.
</body>
```

will display on the web page, however it is conventional to use:

```
<p>
    Place text here.
</p>
```

or other tags for any text or other display. This will allow for easier readability and clarity.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I agree with you that it is better to place text inside a `p` tag when the text is a paragraph and that it displays just fine in a browser without the `p` tag. What I actually meant to ask is whether it is allowed by the HTML standards to place text directly in the body. I will clarify that part in the question.

Comment: This does not answer the question (whether direct text is *allowed*).

Comment: That question was revised to ask if it was allowed by the standards after I answered it.