# Flask display of normal text

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to display a text on the browser but it doesn't show up the css (background color) and the favicon works fine. The text which i want to display are inbetween the html body.

html looks like that:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='globe.ico') }}">
</head>

<body>
  this is a test **// i want to display this line.**
</body>

</html>'
```

Python script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return render_template('index.html')
```

The html is saved in a folder named templates.

Comment: What did you get right now after visting your page using browser?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the HTML version you are using not allowing you to place HTML text directly between `<body>` tags [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412291/text-directly-in-body#:%7E:text=Text%20directly%20inside%20the%20body,views%20of%20good%20coding%20style.).

Either way it is good practice to put your text between another set of tags in your HTML.

So you should do something like this

```
<body>
  <p>this is a test **// i want to display this line.**</p>
</body>
```

or this

```
<body>
  <span>this is a test **// i want to display this line.**</span>
</body>
```

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, because you haven't shared what the output you are currently getting is yet. But it is a good thing for you to do anyway, so I hope it helps.